# Определить максимальное количество подряд идущих положительных элементов

Tags: java, массивы

Необходимо определить максимальное количество подряд идущих положительных элементов, не прерываемых ни нулями, ни отрицательными числами. Например, в данном случае необходимо вывести результирующий массив с элементами `{6, 3, 5, 7, 7, 1}`  А как сделать внешний цикл что бы он перебирал все последовательности чисел между следующими отрицательными числами?

```
    nt[] arr =
    { -1, 3, 4, 5, 9, -7, 6, 3, 5, 7, 7, 1, -9 };
    int startIndex = 0;
    int endIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {   
        for (int k = 0; k < arr.length; k++)
        {
            if (arr[k] > 0)
            {
                startIndex = k;
                System.out.println(startIndex);
                break;
            }
        }
            for (int y = startIndex; y < arr.length; y++)
            {
                if (arr[y] < 0)
                {
                    endIndex = y;
                    System.out.println(endIndex);
                    break;
                }
            }
        int length = endIndex - startIndex;
        System.out.println(length);
    }
```

Comment: А что вы вообще в `arraycopy` хотите добиться, если у вас массив сейчас `0 3 4 5 9 0 6 3 5 7 7 1 0` и `start` будет равен 1 ...... что из него можно вообще понять? У вас логика неправильная уже

Comment: не могу понять как найти самый длинный промежуток и как найти начало и конец. Какая должна быть логика, подскажите пожалуйста?

Comment: ищите неотрицательный и движетесь до отрицательного или конца массива, сравниваем длину с сохраненным максимумоvм, выбираем большее, теперь по кругу

Comment: а как двигаться до отрицательного? @splash58

Comment: индекс массива увеличиваете, пока элемент положительный

Comment: индекс массива увеличивается в цикле `for` но как записывать все элементы до первого отрицательного? их же нужно в массив каким-то образом записывать @splash58

Comment: можно писать в промежуточный массив, можно запоминать идексы начала и конца - этого достаточно для длины

Comment: `int startIndex = 0;
  int endIndex = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
  {
   if (arr[i] > 0)
   {
    startIndex = i;
    System.out.println(startIndex);
    break;
   }
  }
  for (int i = startIndex; i < arr.length; i++)
  {
   if (arr[i] < 0)
   {
    endIndex = i;
    System.out.println(endIndex);
    break;
   }
  }` нашел начало и конец а как узнать длину? необходимо записать в промежуточный массив? @splash58

Comment: исправил, теперь нахожу длину между двумя отрицательными числами, но как теперь пройтись по всему массиву во внешнем цикле? потому что сейчас длину находит только между первыми двумя отрицательными числами @splash58

Answer (score 1):

```java
int[] arr = { -1, 3, 4, 5, 9, -7, 6, 3, 5, 7, 7, 1, -9 };int indexStartBest = -1;
int lengthBest = 0;
int indexStartCurrent = -1;
int lengthCurrent = 0;
for (int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++)
{
    if (arr[i] > 0)
    {
        if (lengthCurrent == 0)
            indexStartCurrent = i;
        lengthCurrent++;
    }

    if (arr[i] <= 0 || i == arr.length-1)
    {
        if (lengthCurrent > lengthBest)
        {
            indexStartBest = indexStartCurrent;
            lengthBest = lengthCurrent;
        }
        lengthCurrent = 0;
    }
}
System.out.println(lengthBest);
```